# ASP.NET: Can an individual SQL record spread its data over a fully user designed template?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I've been trying to get data from a SQL file to populate a set template for a web page. When the user navigates through the database records, the page updates accordingly. The data will include image URLs so that a image will update and things like the alt tag caption and descriptive text should also update.

Its basically a customised gallery based on SQL (text) data.

The .ASP data controls seem very restrictive and even details and form view with templates make it difficult to get full customisation of the layout of data. It there a way to spread data from a database record around a page template (ie HTML/CSS styling) in a consistent manner while maintaining the flexibility of the database functionality?

I basically want to write a HTML layout and put tags in that are replaced by the current field of the database, eg in pseudo code:

```
    <div class="style1"> <asp: SQL_Datafragment field="Title"> </div>
    <div class="picframe">
<img src ="
<asp: SQL_Datafragment field="Image_URL">
"/> />
</div>
    <div style = "caption"> <asp: SQL_Datafragment field="Caption"> </div>
<div style = "spacer"><div>
    <div style = "pictxt"> <asp: SQL_Datafragment field="Description"> </div>
```

And have a navigation control at the bottom like a **prev** and **next** field.

Is this possible?

Many thanks.
Kw

Comment: What data access framework are you using? Raw ADO.NET? Entity Framework? Typed Datasets? And where are you performing the data retrieval - in your code-behind or in the page itself with ASP.NET's Data elements?

Comment: in page with ASP.Net's data controls but the SQL file I built myself and its connecting with a connection string.

Comment: ASP.NET already has an array of methods for data-binding or displaying arbitrary content in a page. I think you need to do more research. You don't need to author custom controls - instead just conform with existing best-practices.